# Entity Framework not using the right type for parameter

Tags: entity-framework

I have a very simple example to demonstrate this issue.

I have a Table Valued Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TestTVF]
(   
    @param1 varchar(max)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT 1 as Id, 'Test' as [Name]
)
```

And I have imported it into a edmx file:

[image]

But when I use the function the sql generate is this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
FROM [dbo].[TestTVF](@param1) AS [Extent1]',N'@param1 nvarchar(4000)',@param1=N'test'
```

This is just an example but in my real world scenario I need to pass in a large xml document that could be to up 300KB.

How do I get Entity Framework to use nvarchar(max) and not nvarchar(4000)?

Comment: is the column nvarchar(max) in the model (e.g. is it configured as .IsMaxLength())?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess Entity Framework will automatically switch the parameter type if the string length is long enough.

Example:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
FROM [dbo].[TestTVF](@param1) AS [Extent1]',N'@param1 nvarchar(max) ',@param1=N'*really long string* ...'
```

I feel stupid for asking this question.